# join with @ prints the wrong result

Tags: perl, arrays, join

I would like to know how can I use the sign `@` together with `join` operator; this yields a wrong result:

```
my $string1  = '00aabb';
my $string2  = '02babe';
print join ("A",@ $string1, $string2);
```

Namely:

```
$ perl b.pl
02babe
```

So how can I use `@` within `join` that would concatenate the two strings and joins them with a separator `A`?
I come out of the assumption that `join` requires an array as its second argument, and it thus should begin with `@`. The mere

```
print join("A", $string1, $string2);
```

works fine, but I want to make it work with `@` preceded.

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Technically `print join("A", @{[ $string1, $string2 ]});` does what you're asking for but `print join("A", $string1, $string2);` is easier to read, works, and will run faster (though unless it's in a loop which is executed billions of times, you're unlikely to notice the speed difference)

Comment: What do you think the `@` is going to do, and why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 6):

[join](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join) does not require an array as its second argument; it requires a list (which is different from an array):

> join EXPR,LIST

Your 2nd code example works fine because the 2nd and 3rd arguments make up a list of 2 items.  Here is a way to use `join` if you already have an array variable (`@strings`):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string1  = '00aabb';
my $string2  = '02babe';

print join ("A", $string1, $string2);
print "\n";

my @strings = ($string1, $string2);

print join ("A", @strings);
print "\n";
```

Prints:

```
00aabbA02babe
00aabbA02babe
```

The `@` sign is what is used to denote an array variable.

See also [perldoc perldata](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata).

---

Note that if you had used `strict`, you would have gotten an error message.